# PHP - How to use functions from another directory file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this function in $root/content/plugins/musicplayer/includes/player.php

```
public function head_script( $id, $playlist_id, $songs, $in_popup, $autoplay = false ) {
        $output   = '';
        $playlist = '';
        $artist   = '';
        $free     = null;
        $external = 0;

        if ( $songs ) {

            $ogg = '';

            foreach ( $songs as $song ) {

                $free = $song->free;

                if ( $song->poster ) {
                    $poster = esc_url( $song->poster );
                } else {
                    $poster = $this->get_default_playlist_poster( $playlist_id );
                }

                $playlist .= '{  title : "' . $song->name . '", mp3:"'. esc_url( $song->mp3 ) .'"';

                if ( $song->artist )
                    $playlist .= ', artist : "' . $song->artist . '" ';


                if ( $free != 'on' ) {

                $playlist .= ',poster : "' . $poster . '" ';


                $playlist .= ' },';
            }

            $playlist = substr( $playlist, 0, -1 );

            $output .= '<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[';

            $output .= "\n";
            $output .= 'jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    new jPlayerPlaylist( {
                        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_' . $id . '",
                        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_' . $id . '" }, 
                        ['.$playlist.'], {
                        swfPath: "' . WOLF_JPLAYER_PLUGIN_URL . '/assets/js/src",
                        wmode: "window", ';

            $output .= '});'; // end playlist

            if ( ! $in_popup )
                $output .= $this->popup();

            $output .= '});'; // end document ready playlist

            $output .= '//]]></script>';
        }

        echo $output;
    }
```

How can I use it in $root/content/themes/bigwolf/index.php, with it still being able to call all the functions that are originally and normally called in the native directory, without any problem?

Comment: As an aside, is this function inside a class?  Normally you don't put "public" in front of the function declaration if it's procedural code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include it. That's how you do it.

f1.php

```
<?php

    function func1()
    {
        echo 'hi';
    }
```

f2.php

```
<?php

    require_once('f1.php'); // require
    //include 'f1.php'; // or include

    func1();
```

Comment: require_once('../../plugins/musicplayer/includes/jplayer-show.php'); can't see why it's not appearing when I do that. the plugins directory is two levels away.

Comment: @CodeFreaks please remove public modifier in your function this can cause troubles.

Comment: Done that, seems that the area I put your code in, it magically disappears, if that makes sense. http://pastebin.com/2E7pfHfY can't see what's wrong

Comment: @CodeFreaks what error are you getting ? Try to add some function like  `function hello_world` which `echo "hello"` and see if there is problem with your function or with something else. If will you have problems write me email.

Comment: Just did a quick test, tried putting player.php in the same directory as where I am trying to call the function and it worked, that's great, but when I move it to one directory above, and call it in this form '../player.php' it will not work. no error. Anyway I'll try to work my way up with it, you provided me with the core to begin with. So thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously musicplayer is a plugin. If it's properly formatted, WordPress will automatically include it. So in the main file of your plugin put

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/includes/player.php';
```

That will bring your player.php in and give you access to the functions in it.

HTH,

=C=

Comment: Actually I'm doing somewhat of a complicated modification to the plugin so I am trying to include some functions from wp-content/plugins/wolf-jplayer/includes/jplayer-show.php in to wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/header.php, I could not do that with your solution.

Comment: If plugins wolf-jplayer is activated and it has the require_once line above, then you will be able to use the functions inside of jplayer-show.php in your theme.

Comment: Ye it is activated, but why does not it show up when I put wp-content/plugins/wolf-jplayer/includes/jplayer-show.php I'm confused because it also makes the whole player disappear.